# Can property path be used to define a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, getjson

I am currently writing a short javascript to call JSON data for a given coordinate from WorldWeather online.  At the moment, I am merely attempting to call one datum before I try to get more elaborate.  I have run my API URL through Postman and the data is present.  My javascript is main.js and referenced in my html.
Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <title>API TEST</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
     integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div>
     <p class="wvht"></p>
   </div>
  </body>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/marine.ashx? 
 key=c45390b6209242f4941174356200201&format=json&q=40.014994,-73.811646",
     function(data){
     console.log(data);

var wvht = data.weather[4].hourly[3].swellHeight_ft;

$(".wvht").append(wvht);
   }
);
```

I am attempting to call the swell height data (swellheight_ft) and am using the path provided in Google DevTools to define the wvht var.  When I run the script, I get my console.log(data) info fine but also get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined
at Object.success (main.js:5)
at fire (jquery-3.4.1.js:3291)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.4.1.js:3421)
at done (jquery-3.4.1.js:9533)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.4.1.js:9785)
 main.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined
```

Where property '4' is referring to the array.  In order to get to the data, I have to drill down through the weather array (7 items) and the hourly array (8 items) to get to the "swellheight_ft".  I am seeking the 4th day in the weather array and the 3rd hour in the hourly array.

Is there a better way to get to the desired swellheight_ft data and avoid the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a silly error but it gets us all at times.  Because your JSON starts with:

```
{"data":
```

and your variable is also named `data`, you are forgetting that you need to first access the `.data` part of the JSON, so just change

```
var wvht = data.weather[4].hourly[3].swellHeight_ft;
```

to

```
var wvht = data.data.weather[4].hourly[3].swellHeight_ft;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Such a small detail and I completely wiffed on it.  Thank you again!